# Google Developer API: "The caller does not have permission" For a service account with Full Admin Access

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I'm trying to setup automation for my App publication via google developer api. I have setup a service account as per the user guide with service account user + owner permissions. The service account shows up on the google play console and I've give it the full Admin access + full access on the app.

[image: Service Account]

[image: Permissions on the service account]

I've created the .json key for the service account as a small test, tried to use google-api-client library on python to see if it works. Note that I have only created a dummy app with a package name and haven't uploaded any APKs yet.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery
import httplib2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
    package_name = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    service_account_file = 'creds.json'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        service_account_file, scopes=scopes)
    
    print(type(credentials))
    # delegated_cre.dentials = credentials.with_subject('rohella.anshuman@gmail.com')
    android = googleapiclient.discovery.build('androidpublisher', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    res = android.edits().insert(body={}, packageName=package_name).execute()
    print(res)
```

However, I keep getting the 403 permission denied error. I've checked all the access on api cloud/play console and it should work as per the official docs. Here is the log output

```
(env) ➜  android-publish python main.py
<class 'google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/xxxxxxxx/android-publish/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    res = android.edits().insert(body={}, packageName=package_name).execute()
  File "/Users/xxxxxxx/Workspace/xxxxxxxx/android-publish/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/xxxxx/android-publish/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.odecloud.odesocial.beta/edits?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission". Details: "The caller does not have permission">
```

Additional Info:

Permissions on google cloud console for the service account user.
[image]

Comment: How exactly did you grant the service account access to your dats?   Did you share it with it?   have you checked that this api supports service account users

Comment: @DaImTo when you create a service account user on Google Cloud Console, it with the Role Service Account User, it automatically shows up on the Google Play Console. After that it's just giving the user all the permissions for an app from the Google Play Console.

Comment: Are you sure **"The caller does not have permission"** Doesn't look like it to me.   TBH i have been working with google serviced accounts for 12 years and that's the first I have heard of it.   I know delegation can be configured via google workspace,  I had no idea it would work with Google cloud like this, do you have any documentation on this feature?

Comment: @DaImTo 
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

The developer API suppoerts service accounts and I have enabled all the required APIs from google console too.

Comment: yes but the service account needs to be granted access just like any other user.   A service account is a dummy user it can only access what it has been granted access to.  "Google Workspace domain administrators can also grant service accounts domain-wide authority to access user data on behalf of users in the domain."

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for your response. Yes, I understand that. That's what the first 2 screen shots show. The googleplay-api-access is the service account which I've added to the developer console as a user and granted all the permissions to on my app. I can take a look at the domain-wide authority part but I feel those permissions are a bit too open. This user is mostly for CI-CD jobs for automated builds.

Comment: try this https://youtu.be/ykJQzEe_2dM

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for taking your time out and posting that video. I have updated the original post and the service acccount user was created with the owner permissions. Seems like that's not quite the issue here.

Comment: with_subject only works if you have configured delegation though google workspace I think.    Im going to have to see if i have access to this api and give it a try myself.

Comment: @DaImTo Sorry for putting up unpolished code but that part is commented out.

Comment: Unfortunately Im busy with a clients project right now im not sure when I will have time to test this for you.